How to build a script to run cucumber .feature (with tags) in maven in Java + IntelliJ
I'm struggling with my .feature file execution. I have different scenarios separated with tags and want to build a sort of script that contains mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="path/to/feature-files --tags @Your_tag" each line.
For example (in js)
"scripts": {
  "test: login": "npx codecept.js run --config=./codecept.conf.mobile.ts --features --grep @login  --verbose
  "test: regression": "npx codecept.js run --config=./codecept.conf.mobile.ts --features --grep @regression  --verbose
}

Note: This is just an example that I got from a friend. My project is in Java.
How can I do this in java using cucumber and maven? how can I execute that?
Thanks in advance.

First make sure you are using the cucumber-junit-platform-engine. If you follow the 10-minute tutorial or copy the skeleton project that should be the case.
Once you have that setup, add some tags and test to see if you've done it correctly by running mvn test -Dgroups="ExampleTag | OtherExampleTag". Note that when running Cucumber with JUnit 5 and Surefire you have to use JUnit 5 tag expressions. These are different from Cucumber tag expressions.
Then you'll want to take a look at Maven Profiles. You can use these to configure multiple executions of Maven Surefire. Each execution of Surefire can be configured to select a tag using the groups xml element.
